# parallel computing of a function with doSMP on Windows

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I'm trying to multicore a function (in Windows), which, at one point, calls another workhorse function (function within function). Here is a minimal working example. You will need `doSMP` and `revoIPC` packages (to get them, see Tal's post [here](http://www.r-statistics.com/2010/04/parallel-multicore-processing-with-r-on-windows/)).

```
func1 <- function(x) {sqrt(x)}
func2 <- function(y) {
    func1(y)
}

library(doSMP)
wrk <- startWorkers(workerCount = 4) #I have 4 cores, so adjust to your specs
registerDoSMP(wrk)

obj.result <- foreach(i = 1:10000) %dopar% func2(i)
```

The above routine doesn't work, but if I nest `func1` within `func2` like so

```
func2 <- function(y) {
func1 <- function(x) {sqrt(x)}
    func1(y)
}
```

the process goes through smoothly (as far as I can tell).

How can I call functions from outside with `%dopar%`?

Comment: This is really weird. When I tried the above example (func1 not nested within func2) today, it worked. I have no idea what's going on. :)

Comment: same issue as you! my func1 is said to be unknow. have you found a solution to load the functions on each compute nodes when using doSMP package?

Comment: I migrated to `snowfall` package, mainly because it's platform independent. It has other benefits, like out-of-the-box usage of apply functions (you just change the name of the apply function, e.g. lapply -> sfLapply).

Comment: correct me if I am wrong I think that doSMP is platform indepedant?
Thanks for your answer

Comment: @Fred If I'm not mistaking, this wasn't always the case (but I may be mistaking)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a *scoping issue*.

Your `func1` is known in the calling workspace but not on the compute nodes.  There are solutions for that, e.g. the [foreach](http://cran.r-project.org/package=foreach) package has an entire vignettes entitled [Nesting Foreach Loops](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/nested.pdf).

Comment: Thank you Dirk for your time, but I don't see how the vignette you mention covers the scoping issue (it may be me being somewhat dense). The code seems to work for now and let's hope it stays that way. I sometimes feel like R is a kind of magic (do you hear music in the background? :) ).

Comment: @ Dirk Eddelbuettel: I have the same issue as @ Roman Lustrik ie: in my case I use the package doSMP as well, and I get an error saying that the function func1 is unknown (but I am sure I have loaded it before). Do I need to do something special? (like creating independent environments?) Also it is worth to mention that Roman example works well on my machine, but not mine which is very similar except that the function func1 and func2 are more complex.

Answer (score 0):

In the foreach function, there is an argument to pass if you have packages to load in order to execute the function fun2

Typically in your example, if fun1 is part of the package PACKAGE1, execute

```
obj.result <- foreach(i = 1:10000, .packages="PACKAGE1") %dopar% func2(i)
```

instead of

```
obj.result <- foreach(i = 1:10000) %dopar% func2(i)
```